# Google Sheets: How to import the following data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Data Source
https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll

I am trying to get the following data onto a Google Sheet, but it is looking to be tricky to do so using IMPORTXML. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a table from the HTML data of the URL.

  - From `I am trying to get the following data onto a Google Sheet`, I thought like this.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that the file size of HTML is large. So when `=IMPORTXML("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll","//title")` is used, an error of `Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.` occurs. When I retrieve HTML data from the URL, the size of HTML data was about 9 MB. It is considered that the reason of error is due to this. So as one of workaround, how about using Google Apps Script? In this workaround, the following flow is used.

1. Retrieve HTML data using `UrlFetchApp`
2. Parse the HTML data using `Parser` which is a GAS library.
3. Put the parsed data to the active sheet on the Spreadsheet using `PasteDataRequest` of Sheets API.

### Usage:

#### Preparation:

1. Please install `Parser`. About the install of library, you can see it at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#managing_libraries).

   - The project key of the library is `M1lugvAXKKtUxn_vdAG9JZleS6DrsjUUV`.
2. [Please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet. After above settings were done, please run the function of `myFunction()`. When the script is run, the table of HTML is put to the active sheet on the Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve HTML data from URL.
  var url = "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll";
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  
  // Parse HTML data.
  var table = "<table" + Parser.data(html).from("<table class=\"t-chart\"").to("</table>").build() + "</table>";
  
  // Put the values to the Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: table, coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}}}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

### References:

- [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Updated at April, 23, 2021:

New IDE for Google Apps Script has finally been released at December 7, 2020. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#december_7_2020) By this, in the current stage, in order to install Google Apps Script library, it is required to use the script ID of Google Apps Script project.

In this case, when the Google Apps Script library of [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html) is installed, unfortunately, this ID `M1lugvAXKKtUxn_vdAG9JZleS6DrsjUUV` cannot be used.

So when you use new IDE, please use the following script ID.

```
1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw
```

This script ID is the ID of Google Apps Script project of `M1lugvAXKKtUxn_vdAG9JZleS6DrsjUUV`. By this, the library of Parser can be installed to the new IDE.

About the method for installing the library, you can see [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project).

#### Reference:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: I was not able to add the Parser library.

Comment: @thdoan Thank you for your comment. About `I was not able to add the Parser library.`, I think that the reason of this issue might be due to the new IDE. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, thanks for the new script ID. Before I got to see your reply I was able to get Parser working by adding Parser.gs from the link you provided (though the code hosted there requires `new Parser(html)` instead of `Parser.data(html)`).